# Does the CHILD_SUBREAPER bit persist across fork()?

Tags: linux, fork

When a process sets the child subreaper bit with `prctl(PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER, 1)` ([documented here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html)), does it need to use `prctl(PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER, 0)` to clear it after a fork?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the child subreaper bit does not persist across forks.

The relevant Linux kernel code [is in `copy_signal()` in `kernel/fork.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/fork.c?v=3.4#L1013): the signal struct is initialized to all zeros, and the `is_child_subreaper` bit is never set.

However, `has_child_subreaper` is set:

```
 sig->has_child_subreaper = current->signal->has_child_subreaper ||                  
                            current->signal->is_child_subreaper;
```

This test program demonstrates the behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

        int pid;
        int i;

        prctl(PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER, 1);

        prctl(PR_GET_CHILD_SUBREAPER, &i);
        printf("Before fork: %d\n", i);

        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
                return 1;
        } else if (pid == 0) {
                prctl(PR_GET_CHILD_SUBREAPER, &i);
                printf("In child: %d\n", i);
                return 0;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Before fork: 1
In child: 0
```